# Как поменять хидер в запросе к Nginx?

Tags: nginx, header

Есть Nginx как реверс прокси и два апстрима. Проблема наблюдается только когда запросы приходят с какого-нибудь UCBrowser. Тогда мы имеем такие заголовки

- 'HTTP_CLIENTIP': ‘117.241.210.33 - реальный адрес клиента
  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': ‘8.37.225.72’ - какая-то прокся
  'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': ‘8.37.225.72’ - какая-то прокся
  'REMOTE_ADDR': '8.37.225.72' - какая-то прокся

Из-за этого проблемы с определением адреса через базы maxmind и пр.

Пробую сделать в server вот так

```
if ($http_http_clientip) {

            set $http_x-real-ip "$http_http_clientip";
        }
```

Не работает. Как заставить Nginx поменять хидер в запросе, если присутствует хидер HTTP_CLIENTIP? То есть, чтобы REMOTE_ADDR тоже показывал реальный адрес клиента, а не левой прокси.

Comment: Это будет дыра в безопасности, если что

Comment: плюс некорректная информация в базе данных.

Comment: А я правильно понимаю, что в HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR пишется вся цепочка адресов? Но у меня в конфиге 
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; 
ТО есть он перезатирается. Может из-за этого тогда неправильно отображать заголовки?